# Using cases on PS Query

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I want a logic in my query where when prompt 2 (:2) is provided a value or is not blank, the STRM field will automatically be equal to the `FIRST_TERM_VALID` field, otherwise `if :2` is black then the `STRM` field equals any.

This is the part of the code:

```
AND A.STRM LIKE ( 
CASE 
WHEN  :2 <> ' ' 
THEN G.FIRST_TERM_VALID 
ELSE '%' 
END
)
```

The problem is with this part of my query, I can no longer pull any results.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic can be a lot simpler:

Either `:2` is null or check if `A.STRM = G.FIRST_TERM_VALID`

```
AND (:2 IS NULL OR A.STRM = G.FIRST_TERM_VALID)
```

Comment: You are assuming BLANK is NULL, which is not true on peoplesoft. Blank is a space.

Comment: @Walucas I'm not assuming anything. I tested both `SELECT * FROM PS_PERSONAL_DATA A WHERE ( :1 IS NULL)` and `SELECT * FROM PS_PERSONAL_DATA A WHERE ( :1 = ' ')`. Results are only returned in the first case. Verified both in PSQuery and straight to db.

Comment: How did u created the prompt on psquery? Which tools are u? I got different results here

Comment: @Walucas So I'm the one assuming things, but you can't even make a query with a prompt? I'm on 8.56.08 and prompts are created in the 'Prompts' tab in PSQuery...

Comment: I know, thats not what I meant.... I assumed u assumed, sorry for that... my prompt here is behaving differently, thats why I asked

Comment: BTW, I was able to simulate it on 8.56..... its null its bringing up, so u are right

Answer (score 0):

If prompt :2 is empty it's more likely to be null.
This could be what you're searching for:

```
and (:2 is null or a.strm = g.first_term_valid)
```

If you want to test for blank too, try this:

```
and (:2 is null or :2 = ' ' or a.strm = g.first_term_valid)
```

Feel free to add expressions. The pattern should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Create an expression on PS Query and use it like a criteria

`AND A.STRM = CASE WHEN :2 IS NULL THEN A.STRM ELSE G.FIRST_TERM_VALID END`